# Find sequential child rows that have amounts which add up to parent row's amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequential

I have a table like following

```
ID  DATE       ACCT  TYPE  AMOUNT    SEQ  CHK#   TRC
1   6/5/2014   1234   C    10,000     1          1001
2   6/5/2014   3333         3,000     2   123    1002
3   6/5/2014   4444         5,000     3   234    1003
4   6/5/2014   5555         2,000     4   345    1004
5   6/5/2014   2345   C     3,000     1          1007
6   6/5/2014   5555         2,500     2   255    1008
7   6/5/2014   7777           500     3   277    1009
8   6/6/2014   1234   C     5,000     1          2001
9   6/6/2014   7777         3,000     2   278    2002
10  6/6/2014   8888         2,000     3   301    2003
```

> The rows with TYPE = C are parent rows to the child rows that follow sequentially.
>   The parent rows do not have CHK# and child rows do have CHK#. Each
>   parent row has seq# = 1 and child rows have sequential numbers. (if it
>   matters) From above table, row ID 1 is the parent row to the rows with
>   ID 2 ~ 4. The AMOUNT on the child rows add up to the parent row's
>   amount.
>
> Querying for transaction for date of '6/5/2014' on account # 2345 with
>   the amount of 3,000 - result should be rows with ID 6 and 7.
>
> Is such query possible using MS-SQL 2008? If so, could you let me
>   know?

Comment: so what is the input to the query the date and account number?

Comment: Date, Account Number, Amount.

Comment: Why does amount matter -- isn't that part of the result?

Comment: Hogan, there may be more than one transactions made to the account on the same date, so I was thinking AMOUNT and TRC may also matter.

Comment: if row ID 5 had ACCT value 1234 instead of 2345, Gordon's query would result with row ID =2, 3, 4, 6, 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on the data that you have, you can use the `id` column to find the rows that you want.  First, look for the one that has the check in that amount.  The look for the subsequent `id`s with the same group.  How do you define the group?  That is easy.  Take the difference between `id` and `seq`.  This difference is constant for the parent and child rows.

So, here is goes:

```
select t.*
from table t
where (t.id - t.seq) = (select t2.id - t2.seq
                        from table t2
                        where t2.type = 'C' and
                              t2.acct = '2345' and
                              t2.date = '6/5/2014'
                       ) and
      t.type is null;
```

Comment: Very nice! but what if the acct on row ID 5 was 1234 and I needed the results with rows ID 6, 7 ?

Comment: You would use `row_number()` on the `id` or `trc` column to generate the sequential values.  That is original what I was going to do, but you had the `id` defined that way already.

Comment: Oh my God, you are genius.